# How do I get the "Edison" achievement in X-Com?

Tags: achievements, xcom-enemy-unknown

I believe I've researched everything. This is what I have researched so far, and I'm at the very end of the game:

- Xeno-biology
- Arc Thrower
- Outsider Shard
- New Fighter Craft
- Hyperwave Communication
- Ethereal Device
- Weapon Fragments
- Alien Materials
- Experimental Warfare
- Elerium
- Psi Armor
- Carapace Armor
- Skeleton Suit
- Titan Armor
- Ghost Armor
- Archangel Armor
- Beam Weapons
- Precision Lasers
- Heavy Lasers
- Plasma Pistol
- Light Plasma Rifle
- Plasma Rifle
- Heavy Plasma
- Plasma Sniper
- Alloy Cannon
- Plasma Cannon
- Fusion Lance
- Guided Fusion Launcher
- Alien Nav Computer
- UFO Power Source
- EMP Cannon
- Interrogate Sectoid
- Interrogate Muton
- Interrogate Sectoid Commander
- Interrogate Berserker
- Interrogate Thin Man
- Interrogate Heavy Floater
- Interrogate Ethereal
- Autopsy Sectoid
- Autopsy Sectoid Commander
- Autopsy Floater
- Autopsy Thin Man
- Autopsy Muton
- Autopsy Chryssalid
- Autopsy Cyberdisc
- Autopsy Berserker
- Autopsy Heavy Floater
- Autopsy Muton Elite
- Autopsy Drone
- Autopsy Sectopod
- Autopsy Ethereal

Have I missed one or is the game bugged?

I'm playing on the Windows/Steam version.

Comment: You have to find another inventor's invention, steal it, and claim it as your own.

Comment: @SaintWacko [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Evergreen_Terrace) :7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to your list, you did not interrogate a Floater.

That is required for getting the achievement.

http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/xcom-enemy-unknown/achievement/69356-Edison.html#3

Comment: Yes, I just couldn't see it, but you're right. I had a Heavy Floater Interrogated, but not a Floater. Thanks!

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - Your list is also missing "Interrogate Muton Elite".

Comment: In total, you're missing: Mechtoid and Seeker Autopsy, and Interrogate Floater and Muton Elite.